# Convert wav in mp3 in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, audio, file-conversion

I've a byte[] in Java Spring Boot that represents a .wav file.
I would like to convert it in a .MP3 file. I tried with JAVE, but it doesnt work. This is my code.

```
public byte[] convertToMP3(byte[] wavByte) {

    File wavFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".wav");
    Files.write(wavFile.toPath(), wavData, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    File outputFile = File.createTempFile("output", ".mp3");
    

    
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("mp3");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);

    
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    MultimediaObject multimediaObject = new MultimediaObject(wavFile);
    encoder.encode(multimediaObject, outputFile, attrs);

    
    byte[] mp3Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(outputFile.toPath());
    return mp3Bytes;
}
```

I've this error

```
unhandled exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3112)
        at ws.schild.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator.copy(DefaultFFMPEGLocator.java:124)
        at ws.schild.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator.copyFile(DefaultFFMPEGLocator.java:109)
        at ws.schild.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator.<init>(DefaultFFMPEGLocator.java:73)
        at ws.schild.jave.Encoder.<init>(Encoder.java:77)
```

is there any way to do it in Spring Boot? What's the problem here?

Comment: Which version of JAVE are you using? Judging by the line numbers in the stack trace it appears to be quite old. 3.0.1 contains [this change](https://github.com/a-schild/jave2/pull/117) which may fix your problem.

Comment: Parameter `wavByte` is not used in the code you posted...

Comment: It's a typo, it's wavData.

@AndyWilkinson thanks for the suggest, actually I'm using JAVE 2, I'll try with JAVE 3.0.1